# VBA Code Help "goto & Select" Alternative

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

This is the first workbook where I have attempted to write some VBA code, and while I have the workbook functioning, I cannot hide the "panel calculations" sheet due to the `goto and select` functions.

Does anyone have another way of getting this result without using these statements?

```
Private Sub Add_Click()

Dim dis As String
Dim mat As String
Dim size As String
Dim qty As String
Dim cst As String
Dim hls As String
Dim bnd As String
Dim sht As String

mat = PanelMatOutput.Value
size = PanelSizeOutput.Value
qty = PanelQuantity.Value
cst = PanelCost.Value
hls = PanelHoles.Value
bnd = PanelBends.Value
sht = Sheettally.Value

Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Panel Calculations").Range("a1"))
Worksheets("Panel Calculations").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select

ActiveCell.Value = qty
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    
ActiveCell.Value = hls
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    
ActiveCell.Value = bnd
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

ActiveCell.Value = mat
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    
ActiveCell.Value = size
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

ActiveCell.Value = cst
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    
ActiveCell.Value = sht
Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Range("h5"))

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd suggest having a read of this answer on SO:  [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0):

As you already know, you can't call sheets data via a macro where the sheet is hidden.

I would suggest the following (pseudo-code, you may need to tweak it slightly)

```
Private Sub Add_Click()

' dims up here

' set variables here

'Prevent the screen from updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Unhide the sheet
Sheets("panel calculations").Visible = True

Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Panel Calculations").Range("a1"))
Worksheets("Panel Calculations").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select

' your active cell bits

' rehide the sheet
Sheets("panel calculations").Visible = False

'permit screen updates again
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

ActiveCell.Value = sht
Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Range("h5"))

End Sub
```

This will unhide your sheet, allow the updates to happen apparently in the background, and then re-hide the sheet when it's done.

Answer (score 0):

No need to unhide/select anything.
This will place the values and leave the selected cell as whatever it was before the code ran.

Note - I'm using `ThisWorkbook` rather than `ActiveWorkbook`.
`ThisWorkbook` is whatever file the code is sitting in,
`ActiveWorkbook` is whatever file is currently active - which can be changed by the user while the code is running.

```
Private Sub Add_Click()

    Dim dis As String
    Dim mat As String
    Dim size As String
    Dim qty As String
    Dim cst As String
    Dim hls As String
    Dim bnd As String
    Dim sht As String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    
    mat = PanelMatOutput.Value
    size = PanelSizeOutput.Value
    qty = PanelQuantity.Value
    cst = PanelCost.Value
    hls = PanelHoles.Value
    bnd = PanelBends.Value
    sht = Sheettally.Value
    
    'Anything starting with "." between With and End With
    'is looking at "Panel Calculations"
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Panel Calculations")
    
        'Find the last row number in column A.
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        
        'Put in the last row in column A (1), B (2), etc.
        .Cells(LastRow, 1) = qty
        .Cells(LastRow, 2) = hls
        .Cells(LastRow, 3) = bnd
        .Cells(LastRow, 4) = mat
        .Cells(LastRow, 5) = size
        .Cells(LastRow, 6) = cst
        .Cells(LastRow, 7) = sht
    End With

End Sub
```